# How would you keep a list of all past and ongoing neuropathic pain medication trials?

Tags: research, pain, neuropathy

What methods would you use?

1. I know https://clinicaltrials.gov/ exists for the US, although I haven't tried searching too much yet.
2. Another idea I have is starting from [fundamental articles like this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1359644605036378#:%7E:text=Neuroinflammation%20is%20a%20more%20restrictive,be%20debilitating%20and%20life%2Ddestroying.) and going to all its citations.
3. Keep an eye on the main journals? Pain? But that's probably years behind certain groundbreaking developments.

What research centers, groups, conferences, or journals are known for this kind of work?
Here's some I know: Pain Week - https://www.painweek.org/, Linda Watkins at University of Colorado, Xalud Therapeutics, maybe someone runs a site similar to https://www.painscience.com/, but with a bigger focus on meds.

What organizations, Twitter accounts, etc. would you follow to stay in the loop?